# SharePoint WebService (as ScriptService)? Why is the return in data.d?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, sharepoint

so I've created a WebService in SharePoint and made it a ScriptService by referencing the respective DLL and using the attribute. I do make the calls in jQuery. Everyhting here works great.

What is a little bit confusing to me is the fact that the returned data is not directly in "data" but in variable called "d". I find this quite annoying.

Can somebody tell why that is and if and how I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because Microsoft AJAX returns data in "data.d" for security reasons. Check out the 
"**Understanding the 'd' Parameter in ASP.NET AJAX JSON Data**" section of this article:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Using%20JSON%20Syntax%20with%20Ajax.ashx